# String operations on Vue variable

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can I make the template dynamic? I want `field.title.arrayName` to be `text1.arrayName`, `text2.arrayName` and so on...

```
Vue.component('box', {
  props: ['field'],
  template: `
      <div>
        <p>Total:{{ field.title + '.arrayName.length' }}</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <card-stack v-for="x in field.title + '.arrayName'" v-bind:course="x"></card-stack>
      </div>
    `
})

new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    fields: [
      { title: 'text1' },
      { title: 'text2' },
    ],
  }
})
```

And that's my HTML:

```
<main>
    <box v-for="x in fields" v-bind:field="x"></box>
</main>
```

Also, text1 and text2 are component names:

```
var text1 = new Vue({
  el: '#text1',
  data: {
    arrayName: [
      { title: 'example' },
    ],
  }
})
```

## note

Please edit my question title as I really don't know how to describe it

Comment: What is exactly `arrayName`?

Comment: text1 and text2 are component names. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

using `eval()` works:

`<p>Total:{{ eval(field.title + '.arrayName.length') }}</p>`

`<card-stack v-for="x in eval(field.title + '.arrayName')" :course="x"></card-stack>`